# Correct way to mock using DI for dependent classes

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I have a situation in a C# code where there are 2 classes or even more classes, where 1 class is dependent on another and so on.

And I am using DI using ninject.

So now I am trying to mock a class but the thing is: mocking that class will require using the mock version of another class as well on which its functionality is related to or dependent upon , So my question is how can this be achieved correctly , is there some thing in ninject that can help achieve this thing exactly, is there any feature built in for this purpose?

Comment: Most of the time, mocking a class (or even better, an interface) will allow to avoid mocking its dependencies. You should only mock the public elements of the highest level dependencies, and bind the mock objects in Ninject

Comment: @jbl Just I am trying to understand your post , although yes i think i meant mocking an interface, so but do i need to bind the mock objects manually? or is there a way to define something some way that would cause the dependent mock objects to bind automatically? is conditional compilation the only way?